# How to create a JSON array and append JSON objects to it?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I'm creating JSON objects from given data.
If an JSON object is created it should be appended to an JSON array which is stored in a bash-variable. This batch of JSON objects should later be send via curl.

Code is:

```
declare -a data=('10.4' '100.23' '20.02');
batch="[]"
for data_object in "${data[@]}"; do
    json=$(jq -n --arg inf $data_object '{data: $inf|tonumber}')
    batch=$(jq '$batch += ["$json"]')
done
```

The expected result after n loops should be:

```
[
   {
      "data": 10.4
   },
   {
      "data": 100.23
   },
   {
      "data": 20.02
   }
]
```

I'm constantly getting this error: `jq: error: $batch is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:`. How can I solve this?

Comment: `batch` is used in shell context, it is not automatically imported to jq's

Comment: Sooo like `batch="[$(printf '{"information": %s}\n' "${data[@]}" | paste -sd,)]"`?

Comment: You don't need any hackery of this sort and can do it all in `jq`. Post a minimal reproducible example with an input and an exact output needed

Comment: Where is `$information` coming from?

Comment: I updated the post so it makes a bit more sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could doubtless make your program work by updating `batch` along the lines of:

```sh
batch=$(jq --argjson json "$json" '. + [$json]' <<< "$batch")
```

However, the approach you're taking seems to be both fragile and astoundingly inefficient. Have you considered accumulating all the items in a file (as a stream of JSON entities), and when they need to be bundled into an array, using `jq -s .`?

In the particular example given, it would in fact be sufficient to write:

```sh
printf "%s\n" "${data[@]}" |
    jq -n '[{data: inputs}]' |
    curl -d @- <OTHER CURL OPTIONS>
```

That is, you can pipe directly into `curl`.

Notice that a call to `tonumber` is unnecessary, whether or not it is known that all the `data` items are numbers.  For reference, `tonumber` is often used in the idiom `(tonumber? // .)` in case the string or other input is not numeric.

### Another variation

If there were other actions to be taken on each data element that jq cannot readily handle:

```sh
batch=$(
   (
       for data_object in "${data[@]}"; do
           jq -n --argjson inf "$data_object" '{data: $inf}'
       done
   ) | jq -s .
)
```

Here, a call to `tonumber` is unnecessary, this time thanks to `--argjson`.

Comment: First of all , thank you for the answer - this is exactly what I needed. I'm always open to learn and find better solutions, especially if mine is actually that bad, so what would be the benefit of storing them in separat files and how would it look like? For further information, the curl that sends the batch is called immediately after the for loop.

Comment: @FlixRo, Added alluded jq -s solution to the answer.